# How do we give constraint on foreign key column based on ERD cardinality?

Tags: sql-server, database, database-design, erd

Let's say I have a 2 tables like below :

**Department**:

```
DeptId   Name
```

**Employee**:

```
EmpId  Name    DeptId
```

Here I have a 0-to-many relationship between `Department` and `Employee` table.

Now when I read the relationship from `Department` to `Employee`, it says 1 department can have 0 or more employees.

Does this mean while creating `Employee` table, I will set `DepartmentId` (foreign key) as null due to zero or many relationship?

And how do we represent 1 or many relationship like for eg If relationship in ERD says 1 department can have 0 or more employees then `DepartmentId` (foreign key) will be non nullable in `Employee` table?

Basically I am just trying to understand how do we give constraint on foreign key based on ERD cardinality (1 to many relation,1 to zero or more relationship).

Can anyone please help me clear this confusion? I will really really appreciate that :)

[image: ERD]

Comment: Right now you are just asking for us to rewrite your textbook with a bespoke tutorial. Tell us what yours is. (Eg give a textbook name, edition & section.) Also there are many methods for doing & diagraming ER design & many cardinality notation styles also. Also this is nevertheless a duplicate many times over. Show the steps of your work following your textbook with justification & ask just 1 specific non-duplicate question re the 1st place you are stuck. Please see [ask], hits googling 'stackexchange homework' & the voting arrow mouseover texts.

Comment: Before considering posting please always google any error message or many clear, concise & precise phrasings of your question/problem/goal, with & without your particular strings/names & site:stackoverflow.com & tags; read many answers. If you post a question, use one phrasing as title. See [ask] & the voting arrow mouseover texts.

Answer (score 1):

> I will set DepartmentId(Foreign key) as null due to zero or many
>   relationship?

**No**, the `Foreign key` should be not null. Imagine you have no employee in table Employee with `DeptId = 1`. So it represents the Department has zero relationships.

Otherwise, the Employee table contains multiple items with `DeptId = 2`, So it represents the 1-n relationships between `Department` and `Employee` table.

Comment: But if you are saying that Foreign Key should not be null So that means all employees have to be in the department.Department Id can also be null against some department in order to represent Zero relationship right?

Comment: Lets say we have an employee John who is not assigned in any department so for John that department Id will be and thats basically our Zero relationship right?

Answer (score 1):

ERD tools are great, but the most powerful design tool is still natural language, predicates, and constraints. So, when in doubt, use a plain text editor instead of an ERD tool. Also do not allow NULLs in the design phase.

```
All attributes (columns) NOT NULL

[p x]   = predicate  x
(c x.y) = constraint x.y

PK = Primary Key
AK = Alternate Key (Unique)
FK = Foreign Key
```

---

Starting with the department, this part does not change.

**[p 1]** Department identified by number `DEPT_ID`, named `DEPT_NAME` exists.

*(c 1.1)* Department is identified by department number.

*(c 1.2)* For each department name, exactly one department has that name; for each department, that department has exactly one name.

```
department {DEPT_ID, DEPT_NAME} -- p 1
        PK {DEPT_ID}            -- c 1.1
        AK {DEPT_NAME}          -- c 1.2
```

---

### Case 1:  Emp `* ---- 1` Dept

**[p 2]** Employee identified by number `EMP_ID`, named `EMP_NAME`, works for department `DEPT_ID`.

*(c 2.1)* Employee is identified by employee number.

*(c 2.2)*  Each employee has exactly one name; for each employee name, more than one employee can have that name.

*(c 2.3)* Each employee works for *exactly one* department; for each department *more than one* employee *may work* for that department.

*(c 2.4)* If an employee works for a department, then that department must exist.

```
employee {EMP_ID, EMP_NAME, DEPT_ID}  -- p 2
      PK {EMP_ID}                     -- c 2.1, c 2.2, c 2.3

      FK {DEPT_ID} REFERENCES department {DEPT_ID} -- c 2.4
```

---

### Case 2:  Emp `* ---- 0..1` Dept

**[p 2]** Employee identified by number `EMP_ID`, named `EMP_NAME`, exists.

*(c 2.1)* Employee is identified by employee number.

*(c 2.2)*  Each employee has exactly one name; for each employee name, more than one employee can have that name.

**[p 3]** Employee identified by number `EMP_ID` works for department identified by number `DEPT_ID`.

*(c 3.1)* Each employee works for *at most one* department; for each department *more than one* employee *may work* in that department.

*(c 3.2)* If an employee works for a department, then that employee must exist.

*(c 3.3)* If an employee works for a department, then that department must exist.

```
employee {EMP_ID, EMP_NAME}  -- p 2
      PK {EMP_ID}            -- c 2.1, c 2.2


emp_dept {EMP_ID, DEPT_ID}  -- p 3
      PK {EMP_ID}           -- c 3.1

      FK1 {EMP_ID}  REFERENCES employee   {EMP_ID}  -- c 3.2
      FK2 {DEPT_ID} REFERENCES department {DEPT_ID} -- c 3.3
```

---

### Case 3:  Emp `* ---- *` Dept

**[p 2]** Employee identified by number `EMP_ID`, named `EMP_NAME`, exists.

*(c 2.1)* Employee is identified by employee number.

*(c 2.2)*  Each employee has exactly one name; for each employee name, more than one employee can have that name.

**[p 3]** Employee identified by number `EMP_ID` works for department identified by number `DEPT_ID`.

*(c 3.1)* Each employee *may work* for *more than one* department; for each department *more than one* employee *may work* in that department.

*(c 3.2)* If an employee works for a department, then that employee must exist.

*(c 3.3)* If an employee works for a department, then that department must exist.

```
employee {EMP_ID, EMP_NAME}  -- p 2
      PK {EMP_ID}            -- c 2.1, c 2.2


emp_dept {EMP_ID, DEPT_ID}  -- p 3
      PK {EMP_ID, DEPT_ID}  -- c 3.1

      FK1 {EMP_ID}  REFERENCES employee   {EMP_ID}  -- c 3.2
      FK2 {DEPT_ID} REFERENCES department {DEPT_ID} -- c 3.3
```

---

### Case 4:  Emp `* ---- 1..*` Dept

This one is tricky, combine cases 1 and 3 by introducing the concept of a home (primary, default) department.

**[p 2]** Employee identified by number `EMP_ID`, named `EMP_NAME`, works for home department `HOME_DEPT_ID`.

*(c 2.1)* Employee is identified by employee number.

*(c 2.2)*  Each employee has exactly one name; for each employee name, more than one employee can have that name.

*(c 2.3)* Each employee works *for exactly one* home department; for each home department more than one employee may work for that home department.

*(c 2.4)* If an employee works for a home department, then that department must exist.

**[p 3]** In addition to the home department, employee identified by number `EMP_ID` also works for another department identified by number `DEPT_ID`.

*(c 3.1)* In addition to the home department, each employee *may work* for *more than one* other department; for each department *more than one* employee *may work* for that department.

*(c 3.2)* If an employee works for a department, then that employee must exist.

*(c 3.3)* If an employee works for a department, then that department must exist.

```
employee {EMP_ID, EMP_NAME, HOME_DEPT_ID}  -- p 2
      PK {EMP_ID}                          -- c 2.1, c 2.2, c 2.3

      FK {HOME_DEPT_ID} REFERENCES department {DEPT_ID} -- c 2.4


emp_dept {EMP_ID, DEPT_ID}  -- p 3
      PK {EMP_ID, DEPT_ID}  -- c 3.1

      FK1 {EMP_ID}  REFERENCES employee   {EMP_ID}  -- c 3.2
      FK2 {DEPT_ID} REFERENCES department {DEPT_ID} -- c 3.3
```

On the application level check that, for a given employee, `HOME_DEPT_ID` is not repeated as `EMP_ID` in the `emp_dept`.

Answer (score 0):

It wouldn't be null because every employee has a department. A department can have zero employees though, meaning its ID is in none of the employee rows.