# Database Modelling, Structures, and Relationships

Tags: database, database-design, relational-database, database-schema

Currently I'm designing a database model that would serve as a database for an inventory system. However, I'm facing difficulties in the database structures particularly on whether I would add an extra column for the parent table for it's child ID.

Presented in the figure below is a part of the database that I'm currently working on. I'm working on the Normalization forms that's why it already has multiple tables. However, in the Shipment Table (highlighted in blue) in this case the parent table of Shipment Details (highlighted in red) I don't know if I should include an extra column for the shipment table for it to identify or connect to the Shipment Detail table.

I already included a foreign key for the Shipment Detail for it to identify which Shipment it relates to I just don't know if I should add another ID column for the details in the Shipment table. To be more specific, should I add a "Shipment Detail ID" column for the Shipment table? I worry it might result to redundancies if I include it.

[image]

Comment: The shipment detail table is the rows satisfying the relations(ship)/association "shipment detail [sd] is about shipment [sid] and ...". Projecting on those columns happens to give the rows satisfying the relation(ship)/association "shipment detail [sd] is about shipment [sid]". Why do you need another relation(ship)/association from which you can also express/extract it?

Comment: In what way are you are stuck following your design method reference? Why aren't you mentioning that method's steps? You are essentially hoping we'll guess which method it is & rewrite the applicable parts of the relevant presentation. With barely a specification by which to judge/determine a design. Follow a published academic textbook on information modelling, the relational model & DB design. (Manuals for languages & tools to record & use designs are not such textbooks.) (Nor are wiki articles or web posts.) Ask 1 specific researched non-duplicate question about the 1st place you get stuck.

Comment: Please [use text, not images/links, for text--including tables & ERDs](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/3404097). Use images only for what cannot be expressed as text or to augment text. Include a legend/key & explanation with an image.

Comment: @philipxy sorry I saw other questions with a reference to a picture or a figure to database design and modeling that's why I thought it would be okay to do it. I'm having difficulty on whether I should also include the primary key from the "Shipment Details" table to the "Shipment" table to establish a relationship between the two tables. Or is the current set-up where the child table will only contain the primary key "Shipment" table enough to establish such "1 to 1" relationship?

Comment: It would help if you described the business domain in natural language - as it stands, the model doesn't make a lot of sense to me. Once we understand the business domain, the schema design is much easier

Comment: @CzarLuc BTW, unless you have *Visio Plan 2*, best not to use it for any serious DB design, required features are simply not there.

Comment: Sorry I just thought to describe one table that I have a problem on so it would be easy to understand. Will take note of this when I post another question regarding this project. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If each `shipment` has exactly one `shipment detail`

```
shipment {SHIPMENT_ID, ...}
      PK {SHIPMENT_ID}


shipment_detail {SHIPMENT_ID, ...}
             PK {SHIPMENT_ID}

             FK {SHIPMENT_ID} REFERENCES
       shipment {SHIPMENT_ID}
```

If each `shipment` can have more than one `shipment detail`

```
shipment {SHIPMENT_ID, ...}
      PK {SHIPMENT_ID}


shipment_detail {SHIPMENT_ID, SHP_DET_NO, ... }
             PK {SHIPMENT_ID, SHP_DET_NO}

             FK {SHIPMENT_ID} REFERENCES
       shipment {SHIPMENT_ID}
```

Notes:

```
All attributes (columns) NOT NULL

PK = Primary Key
AK = Alternate Key (Unique)
FK = Foreign Key
```

Comment: In the second example, this is like a "1 to many" relationship so would the shipment table have another column for an the "SHP_DET_NO" or is it unecessary to add since the shipment_detail table already has a "SHIPMENT_ID" on its own?

Comment: @CzarLuc, no exactly as is here. In the second example the detail `PK {SHIPMENT_ID, SHP_DET_NO}` may look like `(1,1), (1,2), (1,3), (2,1), (2,2) ..`

Comment: @CzarLuc May I suggest that you switch to natural language design methods, which will keep your tables in high NF, even if you do not (currently) quite understand all the nuances. For example take a look at:
https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/262601/need-help-with-bcnf-decomposition-problem/262793#262793

Comment: Thank you!! Are all "1 to many" relationships modeled like this?

Comment: Sorry I don't know any program that uses the natural design methods. Is there any that you can suggest? Or is it just formatted in Word?

Comment: @CzarLuc Your most powerful tool is a plain text editor and reasoning (logic). Once you get a "feeling" for that one, use  ERD tools. Take a look at this one
https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/73966/should-i-add-transitive-foreign-keys/74096#74096

Comment: @CzarLuc for 1-to-many etc take a look at:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60245854/how-do-we-give-constraint-on-foreign-key-column-based-on-erd-cardinality/60265200#60265200

Answer (score 1):

It depends. If you want a Shipment to have many ShipmentDetails then no, because you're going to repeat ShipmentDetailId in the Shipment table for every child it has, an thus violating 1FN.

[image: Simple Select to see the potential results]

If you have a "1 to 1" relationship, having two tables might not be necessary because you can have everything in just the Shipment table.

I've seen tables that became too large in columns amount let's say, but I've never seen a performance boost for separating the columns in different tables.

Hope this helps!

Comment: I think the latter is what is needed since there is a "1 to 1" relationship between the tables. With that said, so is it okay to merge the tables without any complications in the large number of columns? I was stuck thinking about it due to the Normalization forms and thought separating the tables would be necessary.

Comment: Follow-up question with another table with regard to the "Receive Shipment Item" table, following with what you said I have a "1 to many" relationship with the "Shipment" to the Receive Shipment Item" so should I include a "Shipment Item ID" (Foreign key) in the "Shipment" table? Since one Shipment can have many items

Comment: In my experience, a large number of columns is not a problem if you design your indexes accordingly. If you have your queries in mind, lets say that you have two or three UI views designed, then you can put the columns you need using the INCLUDE clause, check this article https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/3511/sql-server-covering-index-performance/

Comment: Regarding the Shipment item Id, same as before, I mean, the detail must have the FK to his parent, in this case RecieveShipmentItem should have ShipmentId (if I got it right). BUT --> Keep in mind that if I order 3 ítems, is posible that I got them in different deliveries, right? If that's the case, I would go with a many to many relationship using an intermediate table. Regards!